# Is $f(x,y)$ = $e^\frac{1}{1-x^2-y^2}$ if $x^2+y^2<1$ and $0$ if $x^2+y^2\ge1$ differentiable?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I need to check if $f(x,y)$ is differentiable over it's domain.

$$f(x,y) =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  e^\frac{1}{1-x^2-y^2}  & \mbox{if } x^2+y^2<1  \\
  0 & \mbox{if } x^2+y^2\ge1
 \end{array}
\right.$$

I can see that $f(x,y)$ if differentiable for $x^2+y^2<1$. Indeed

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=-\frac{2e^\frac{1}{1-x^2-y^2}x}{(1-x^2-y^2)^2}\in C^1(x^2+y^2<1)$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)=-\frac{2e^\frac{1}{1-x^2-y^2}y}{(1-x^2-y^2)^2}\in C^1(x^2+y^2<1)$$

But I'm not sure how to study the case $x^2+y^2\ge1$.

Comment: Check the function definition, please. The question is interesting only if the exponent $\to-\infty$ in the region where the function is non-zero.

Comment: This function is used as a "mollifier" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier)

Answer (score 2):

It has been treated many times here that the function $$p(t):=\left\{\eqalign{e^{-1/t}&\qquad(t>0)\cr 0\quad&\qquad(t\leq0)\cr}\right.$$ behaves strangely at $t=0$, but is $C^\infty$ on all of ${\mathbb R}$ nevertheless.

Your function $f$ of  $(x,y)$ can be viewed as composition of the smooth function $$g:\quad (x,y)\mapsto 1-x^2-y^2$$ with the $p$ above:
$$f=p\circ g:\quad (x,y)\mapsto\left\{\eqalign{\exp\left({-1\over 1-x^2-y^2}\right)&\qquad(x^2+y^2<1)\cr 0\quad\qquad&\qquad(x^2+y^2\geq1)\ .\cr}\right.$$
This implies that $f$ is a smooth function of $(x,y)$ in the complete plane ${\mathbb R}^2$.